# xkb - Remapped modifiers still work as modifiers

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm using xkb to create my own keyboard layout. I have a slight problem, though.

```
key <AE04> {[ Shift_L ]};
key <AE07> {[ Shift_R ]};
key <LFSH> {[ comma  , semicolon , bar    ]};
key <RTSH> {[ period , colon     , period ]};
modifier_map Shift { <AE04>, <AE07> };
```

The above moves the shift keys to other keys. In order to make the new shift keys actually do something when pressed, I had to add the `modifier_map` line. The code also puts regular characters on the old shift keys. So far so good.

The problem is that if I hold down the old left shift key and press some character - lets say "a" - I get ",A". So that key works both as a comma key *and* as a shift key. The latter is not desired. The same thing happens with the right old shift key. In fact, it also happens with control and alt.

How do I solve this? It feels like I need `modifier_unmap` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `setxkbmap -print` I realized that `pc` was included in the symbols list. That symbol file sets up the regular modifiers, which is not desired by me.

Before, I had added my own layout to the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` directory and to the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` file. That made my layout appear in the GUI to select keyboard layout.

A solution is to make a keyboard layout from scratch instead. One that does *not* include the `pc` file. However, there are a lot of standard keyboard stuff in `pc` that I need. So I read through that file top to bottom picking out the things I needed.

In short, creating a layout from scratch basically means:

1. Copy the output of `setxkbmap -print` to a file.
2. That file just includes other files. Look through the list to see what you can reuse. For me, it meant replacing `pc` with the name of my own file.
3. Create new files if needed.
4. Launch your new layout using `xkbcomp -I$HOME/additional-include-folder file-from-step-one`.

I learned this (in more detail) from this excellent guide: http://hack.org/mc/writings/xkb.html.